# German letters with double umlauts?

Tags: pdftex, input-encodings, german

I'm trying to use german umlauts in my document, however if I use it like that:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{atbegshi}% http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi
\AtBeginDocument{\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\graphicspath{{Bilder/}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\centerline{\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{Deckblatt.png}}
\end{center}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Voraussetzungen f{\"Ä}r  das Programm}

Wenn Sie das Programm nutzen mchten, benigen sie die aktuellste Version von Java.

\end{document}
```

It is shown with double umlauts above for some reason, why is that?

[image: double colons]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Use either `fÄr` (recommended) or `f\"Ar`, but not both.

Comment: They're growing/reproducing!! `#blumlauts`

Comment: Are you sure your files are encoded in `ansinew`? Not `utf8`, which is the standard for years?

Comment: That's not the output I'm getting from that code.  As an aside, the code is short enough but there is still a lot of redundant cruft.

Comment: Did my answer helped you? If yes, please consider accepting and upvoting it. That is the way here to say "Thank you for your help"!

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is an issue with your file encoding.

See the following reduced code

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493504/german-letters-with-double-umlauts
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc} % <======================================


\begin{document}

\section{Voraussetzungen f{\"u}r  das Programm} % <=====================

Wenn Sie das Programm nutzen m\"ochten, ben\"otigen sie die aktuellste Version von Java.

\end{document}
```

with ansi encoding (see red circle) in the image showing editor TeXnicCenter with the code above in ansi encoding:

[image: editor texniccenter]

Compiling this returns the following pdf (please see that I used the correct `\"u` for `ü`, `\"o` for `ö` etc. and not your wrong code!):

[image: resulting pdf]

Nowadays encoding utf8 is the standard, see the following code (you can use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` or leave it out, with current TeX distribution utf8 is standard and neeeds not to be called):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % <====================================== utf8 is standard now


\begin{document}

\section{Voraussetzungen für  das Programm} % <=====================

Wenn Sie das Programm nutzen möchten, benötigen sie die aktuellste Version von Java.

\end{document}
```

and in editor it needs to have encoding utf8 (see red circle in screenshot):

[image: code in utf8 in editor]

and the resuting pdf:

[image: resulting pdf with utf8]

As you can see the written code is much better readable with real german umlauts ...